# List all Starred messages in Thunderbird sidebar

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

In Outlook, I can see all messages marked as Follow-up in the sidebar:

[image]

Is it possible to do the same with Thunderbird?
Is there an extension that does that?

Having a special folder that shows all Starred, or having the Starred messages appearing on the top of each mailbox isn't what I'm looking for.
I want to have a always-visible list of every message I star.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is a way to have an always available list of Starred messages.

https://coffeeonthekeyboard.com/all-starred-messages-in-thunderbird-3-369/

The best you may be able to do is create a Saved Search:

```
But you can create a new saved search. Here’s how:

1 Go to File > New > Saved Search…
2 Name it something like “Starred”
3 Set “Create as a subfolder of:” to wherever you’d like the folder to live.
4 Click “Choose” to pick which folders to search.
5 Change the filter to “Status” “is” “Starred”.
6 Save it.
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you. However, I am already aware of that solution and said in my original question: "Having a special folder that shows all Starred, or having the Starred messages appearing on the top of each mailbox isn't what I'm looking for."